# Finding nearest airport in Swift

Tags: swift, location-services

Is it possible to find the nearest airport ICAO using location services? Just the airport name would be good enough.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035597/find-nearest-airport-using-ios) about the same topic, but after 11 years, I would think by now there would be a better way.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I've done some research and that question is all I've found. I would've provided some code if I had enough to even make something up.

Comment: You can obtain the information via the same platform in your quoted question. The REST API URL is:  http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyJSON?lat=40&lng=9&radius=250&username=YOUR_USERNAME&featureCode=AIRP. Get username from https://www.geonames.org/login. Documentation at: http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll check it out.

Comment: You can find tons of tutorials online on how to make an API call in Swift.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use MapKit in Swift to find airport: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpointofinterestcategory/3143421-airport